# What does "drink like a professional" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Scott Fitzgerald

> always drank like a professional, collapsing the arc from charming to churlish early on.

This sentence is from [a review by P. Green of ’Z: A Novel of Zelda Fitzgerald’ in The NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/04/21/books/review/z-a-novel-of-zelda-fitzgerald-by-therese-anne-fowler.html?pagewanted=1&_r=2&ref=books&).

Does it mean he drank a lot and alcohol turned him "from charming to churlish"? I am not sure.

And how to understand “early on” here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have answered it yourself. It sounds correct to me. I think it means he drinks a lot and shortly after beginning to drink reaches from a good mood (after drinking a little!) to a bad mood (after continuing to drink), from feeling charming to become rough and violent.

[Early on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/early+on) means "hortly after the beginning."

Comment: +1 "Early on" likely referred to whenever he showed up somewhere, such as at a party, he would indulge in drinking right away and be drunk very "early on" in the evening.

Answer (score 2):

"Drink like a professional" means "to consume a beverage (most likely alcohol) in the productive, efficient manner of someone who is paid to do so as a job".

This is not a special English usage; it translates directly into other languages.

Comment: Hi Kaz, is the quoted definition you have there from a source, or did you invent it?

Comment: Drinking *like a professional* implies greater dedication than being someone who has [the odd tipple](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+odd+tipple%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but the real boozers are those who [can drink for England](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22drink+for+england%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: The quotes are not a *definition*, but a transliteration (paraphrasing). This is my own and comes from my understanding of "to drink" and "professional" as an English speaker. The purpose is to show that the words essentially have their ordinary meaning.

Comment: @Kaili In your native language, is there some word for a professional which means someone who does something for a living, with connotations that he or she is very good at it (precise, efficient, productive, dedicated, ...). And can that word be used sarcastically? Similarly to "professional thief", or "professional drunk"?

Comment: @Kaz Yes.In Chinese you can say "zhi ye xiao tou"(professional thief), meaning he or she is very good at it and can make a living, but not so sarcastically. When you say someone is"zhi ye jiu tu"(professional drunk) or “zhi ye ma jiang shi”(professional Mahjongg player), that is much more  sarcastically, becuase people usually assume that one cannot make a living by drinking or playing Mahjongg(though some people really can win money)Sorry my written English is so terrible.

Comment: @Kaili Actually "professional thief" isn't really sarcastic either. Thieves who are "real pros" get in and out, and nobody knows how. Nothing forced, no big mess, no fingerprints, etc.  Professional thieves are successful, and so they are above professional drunks.

Comment: @Kaz I thought “drink like a professional” might mean he knew alcohol and drinking etiquette very  well, and looked like an expert.I was confused, but now not any more. Thanks.

Comment: I am only wondering how one can know the etiquette of drinking but drinks too much that turns his/her mood from good to bad quickly?! I am not a professional drinker but as a newbie in drinking a little during months I think the etiquette of drinking means how to taste a drink and when drink it and how much to not make your mood bad and terrible. If not so what is a difference between an expert drinker with a newbie drinker like me?! Am I not better than him/her? &^)

Comment: @PersianCat  when I googled "Drink Like a Professional", I found  webpages like http://www.nzherald.co.nz/lifestyle/news/article.cfm?c_id=6&objectid=10678502 and  http://bitchbuzz.com/life/how-to-keep-your-holiday-sparkle-avoid.html That was why I was not so sure.

Comment: As to "it translates directly into other languages," in Italian _bere come un professionista_ (the translation of "to drink like a professional") is not something said for who drinks much; you would say _bere come una spugna_ ("drink like a sponge cloth").

Comment: @kiamlaluno Your point seems to be that a literal translation of "drink like a professional" isn't a common phrase in other languages which is true, but note that it's also not common in English, and we also have "drink like a sponge" (I've never head "drink like a professional", but I can readily understand it). "Translates into other languages" is not the same thing as "is a common phrase in other languages".

Comment: I meant that _bere come un professionista_ is not an Italian idiomatic expression. If by "it translates into other languages" you mean "it has an equivalent in other languages," then that is probably true of almost all the English expressions. The fact there is an equivalent expression in other languages doesn't mean the OP should know what "drink like a professional" means.

Comment: @kiamlaluno No, by "translates to other languages" I mean "translates to other languages" and not "it has an equivalent in other languages". In anticipation of this possible confusion, I deliberately wrote "*directly* translates".

Comment: That can be said for other English expressions as well. I still don't get why it is relevant to say that for "drink like a professional."

Comment: @kiamlaluno It can be said for other English expressions, but not *all* other English expressions. What is relevant is that the expression is not a special idiom, but ordinary. It invokes a metaphor which has clear semantics independent of language. If OP doesn't know what "drink like a professional" means, it's not really an English problem.

Comment: Whatever an English expression is ordinary or a special idiom doesn't depend from other languages. As a matter of fact, there are languages that don't use that expression, but that doesn't change how that expression is considered in English. Also, it is perfectly legitim for the OP to wonder if the expression is about _quantity_ or _quality_.

Answer (score 1):

Like a professional is a whimsical/facetious usage here. The sense is that he took drinking seriously. He wholeheartedly threw himself into getting drunk quickly (early on means after not much time) and efficiently. Which unfortunately meant he soon became rude/tiresome/boorish/churlish, rather than energised/witty/charming.

- [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers-reinstate-monica?tab=profile)