# What does "drink for England" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions, phrase-meaning

I found it in one of comments on [What does "drink like a professional" mean in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6146/what-does-drink-like-a-professional-mean-in-this-context)

> Drinking like a professional implies greater dedication than being someone who has the odd tipple, but the real boozers are those who can ***drink for England***.

I understand the sentence except for the bold part. Is it an idiom or expression?

Comment: It means a world-class drinker; one who drinks so much he would be selected for the national drinking team, if there was such a thing.

Comment: @StoneyB Really?! We will know... :)

Comment: I believe this is common throughout the islands, with occasional and local variants *drink/talk/whinge/sleep/&c for England/Scotland/Wales/Ireland.*

Comment: @StoneyB you should merge those comments into an answer, because there won't be a more accurate one than that!

Comment: @StoneyB, oops, I didn't see your comment before posting an answer. Sorry.

Comment: @Daniel That's quite all right. if I'd felt up to posting an answer I would have done so, and as far as I'm concerned the race goes to whoever who actually crosses the finish line! :)

Comment: @StoneyB haha well I'm not trying to race anybody and I generally feel that if somebody posts a comment that answers the question, they should have the opportunity to post the answer and reap the reputation reward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that if there were a drinking competition and England (a country known for its drinking) needed to select someone to compete in its national team, they would select that person.

Comment: Yes, but it's worth pointing out (as per [this Wikipedia discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Language/2008_June_17#can_talk_for_England)) that it's a form used for many things: *"could sleep for England"; "could whinge for England"; and so on.* Not necessarily activities that the English in particular are known for. The same format occurs (somewhat less often) for *Scotland, Wales, Ireland*, but I've never come across *"He could xxxxx for America"*.

Comment: I was surprised that some English language natives do not recognize the difference between prejudice and a tag against sex discrimination and prejudice. I think you can win the competition.. Drinking for England! :)) Do not take it as an offense.. I love humor and know you love it too. You are not prejudiced! ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Except in Olympic years, America does not have national teams in any of what are regarded as the 'major' team sports - baseball, football, basketball and hockey. Consequently,  *play for [the country]* (which I take to be the idiom which gives rise to all the others) does not designate the peak of athletic achievement here. Our equivalent would be "he's a *major league* drinker" or "he's an *NFL-/NBA-/NHL-class* drinker".

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, we already had the basic idea long before national (sports) teams - ['Once more unto the breach' - is from the '**Cry God for** Harry, **England**, and Saint George!' speech of Shakespeare's Henry V, Act III, 1598.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/269700.html) We don't cry for God so much these days though.

Comment: @StoneyB Seriously, combine thiat with your comments on the question and I think you could write a much more thorough answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Um. That doesn't mean Henry's soldiers are so good at "crying God" that they've been selected to do it on England's behalf. They've been selected as soldiers, so I suppose anything they then do is "for England", but here they literally are told they should shout out "God for Harry, England and St George!" on the battlefield. And yes, these days it's considered a little tasteless to say God's on England's side against the other lot, although I think Blair managed it a time or two.

Answer (score 1):

"Can drink for England" means a **world class** drinker. Someone who could represent England in an international drinking competition (if one were ever held).

Answer (score -4):

First of all I think, it has nothing to deal with drinking habits.
To me it seems an idiom in which the writer is expressing a *tendency of having it easily of [here] England*.